# csv writing error

Tags: python, csv

I am writing different csv files from a single csv file(data_labelled.csv)
based on column 32(It contain different node name), i want a separate file for each node.

csv file :

```
2040696 58.475039683    4.6011785714    4.9225238095    1.3880952381    550.2218254 968424.34127    1046524 job_1456818565071_0001  task_1456818565071_0001_r_000000    REDUCE  aditi   0
2040692 56.9    5.89    6.12    2   543.66666667    1045940 1046524 job_1456990723980_0001  task_1456990723980_0001_r_000000    REDUCE  kalpesh 0
2040692 56.9    4.5633333333    5.2066666667    3   544 1045940 1046524 job_1456990723980_0001  task_1456990723980_0001_r_000000    REDUCE  kalpesh 0
2040692 56.9    3.9 4.75    3   544 1045940 1046524 job_1456990723980_0001  task_1456990723980_0001_r_000000    REDUCE  kalpesh 0
2040696 57.1    8.63    10.356666667    19.666666667    573 1046524 1046524 job_1456990723980_0001  task_1456990723980_0001_m_000000    MAP pooja   0
2040696 57.1    11.82   14.55   29  626 1046524 1046524 job_1456990723980_0001  task_1456990723980_0001_m_000000    MAP pooja   0
2040696 57.1    11.82   14.55   29  626 1046524 1046524 job_1456990723980_0001  task_1456990723980_0001_m_000000    MAP pooja   0
```

As per the code there should be having three different files pooja.csv , kalpesh.csv, aditi.csv but only kalpesh.csv is correctly done other two are empty.

code :

```
file = csv.reader(open('data_labelled.csv','r'))
print node_list
for node in node_list:
    filename = '{}.csv'.format(node)
    file2_obj=open(filename,'w')    
    file2 = csv.writer(file2_obj)
    entries=list(file)
    for entry in entries:
        if(entry[32] == node):
            file2.writerow(entry)
    file2_obj.close()
```

result for node_list is good :

```
[u'kalpesh', u'aditi', u'pooja']
```

but why the other two files are empty?
What's going wrong ?

Comment: When you do `entries=list(file)`, it exhausts the data so that next time you are getting only empty list. Check out the answer below which is simply to put that statement out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `entries=list(file)` out of the loop, that is where the problem is.

Your code should look like the following.

```
file = csv.reader(open('data_labelled.csv','r'))
entries=list(file)
print node_list
for node in node_list:
    filename = '{}.csv'.format(node)
    file2_obj=open(filename,'w')    
    file2 = csv.writer(file2_obj)
    for entry in entries:
        if(entry[32] == node):
            file2.writerow(entry)
    file2_obj.close()
```

Comment: thanks sir it worked   but sir after sometime it started giving me null values for some entries . What can be the reason for that?

Comment: @AnkitG. What do you mean by null values for some entries? How do you detect those null values?

Comment: Actually i using Ganglia for getting data for this. So, initially i assign the whole 2-d array as 'nan' values and then i write the data in that 2-d array and then convert it to .csv file. So, some entries were nan ,  hence i asked you. but i think it may be Ganglia problem for not recording data. I am working on it,any suggestion are welcomed :)